# How to convert a list to dict with duplicate keys?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am a freshman in python programming. Now I have a list "lst" like : `lst = [(1,'a'), (2,'b'), (2,'c'), (3,'d')]` and I want to get a dict "d" from lst. "d" should be `{1: ['a'], 2:['b','c'], 3:['d']}`.

```py
d = defaultdict(list)

for k,v in lst:
    d[k].append(v)
```

How can I achieve this using comprehension?

Comment: Your approach looks neat to me

Comment: comprehensions are just for convenience. You don't have to write everything in comprehension it doesn't offer anything more than a plain for-loop. Your code is readable and concise.

Comment: I agree with the other comments; your code is fine. If you want to have it on one line just do `for k,v in lst: d[k].append(v)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You solution is pretty good. list/dictionary comprehensions are not always the best approach. But If you insist, you can do something like:

```py
from itertools import groupby

lst = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd')]

res = {k: [b for a, b in g] for k, g in groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x[0])}
print(res)
```

output:

```
{1: ['a'], 2: ['b', 'c'], 3: ['d']}
```

**note:** This solution would work if you pass a sorted list, If it's not, make sure you sort the list before using it in the dictionary comprehension (Thanks @Chepner)

```
sorted_lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: Replace `lst` with `sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[0])` if it isn't already sorted by the dict keys.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is already quite efficient and not that long.  It could be converted to a one-liner at the expense of legibility with little or no performance benefit:

like this:

```
dic = next(g  for g in [{}] if not any(g.setdefault(k,[]).append(v) for k,v in lst))
```

Or this:

```
dic = {}; dic.update((k,dic.get(k,[])+[v]) for k,v in lst)
```